# multer. How can I skip a file if it is on disk?

Tags: node.js, multer

How can I skip a file using multer upload if it is already on disk? It re-downloads and updates when I use the following code

attachments.component.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class FilesUploadComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onFileChange = this.onFileChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            imgCollection: ''
        }
    }

    onFileChange(e) {
        this.setState({ imgCollection: e.target.files })
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        let formData = new FormData();
        for (const key of Object.keys(this.state.imgCollection)) {
            formData.append('imgCollection', this.state.imgCollection[key])
        }
        axios.post("/api/attachments/upload", formData, {
        }).then(() => {}).catch(() => {})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="FIO" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="file" name="imgCollection" onChange={this.onFileChange} multiple />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

attachments.router.js

```js
let express = require('express'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    router = express.Router(),
    Attachment = require('../models/Attachment');

const DIR = './public/';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileName = file.originalname;
        cb(null, fileName)
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});



router.post('/upload', upload.array('imgCollection'), async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const reqFiles = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
            const file_name = 'public/' +req.files[i].filename
            reqFiles.push(file_name)
            const find = await Attachment.findOne({ file_name: file_name })
            if(find){
                return res.status(400).json( { message: 'File ' + file_name + ' already save' } )
            }
        }
        console.log(reqFiles)
        reqFiles.map(async name => {
            const attachment = new Attachment({
                file_name: name
            })
            await attachment.save()
        })
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Files saved' })
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Attachment.model.js

```js
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose')

const schema = new Schema({
    file_name: {
        type: String, required: true, unique: true
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
})

module.exports = model('Attachment', schema)
```

Ideally, I would like to first perform some operations in mongodb, then give the correct answer to the user, but to get the necessary data, I first save the files using multer. Tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the `fileFilter` function. Here's a full example:

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const UPLOAD_DIR = '/tmp/'

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(UPLOAD_DIR, file.originalname))) {
        console.log('skipped')
        cb(null, false)
        return
    }

    cb(null, true)
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, UPLOAD_DIR)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const fileName = file.originalname;
        cb(null, fileName)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    fileFilter,
    storage,
});

app.post('/', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
    res.send('Uploaded!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Fine! Then how can you cancel downloading all files if at least one of them already exists on the disk?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. When is this download happening exactly?

Comment: Occurs before the route is processed. I have attached the file in the post

Comment: Do you actually mean "upload" instead of "download"? If I understand now, you receive a list of files and if at least one of them, you want to cancel the whole process. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, I upload files to my hosting from a form. And if at least one of the list of files is already present on the hosting, then cancel the download of all files that were added with it

Comment: You can't do this with multer. You would have to implement this at a lower level with something like busboy, which [multer uses to parse the incoming request](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/lib/make-middleware.js). Anyway, even with this approach the file's data will already be on the server side. You would not really be cancelling the upload because it had already happened. You can always save the files to a temp dir, check if any of them exist in your definitive file storage, respond, remove temp files.